# Манипуляции со списками

Tags: haskell

Помогите, пожалуйста, написать программу, которая сначала меняет элементы списка по формуле

```
a[i]=a[i]+a[i-1] для i>0
```

затем удаляет все нечетные элементы, которые меньше среднего арифметического.

Не нашел, как индексироваться по списку, максимум что удалось это прибавлять или отнимать от элемента что-нибудь, либо прибавлять или отнимать конкретный элемент:

```
func (xs) = [ x+xs!!0 | x <- xs]
```

Answer (score 1):

«индексироваться по списку», в принципе, конечно, можно, но, насколько я понимаю, это совсем «нефункциональный путь».

---

> меняет элементы списка по формуле a[i]=a[i]+a[i-1] для i>0

если считать, что нумерация начинается с нуля, то, например, так:

```
f [] = []
f (x:xs) = x:(f1 x xs) where
  f1 _ [] = []
  f1 n (x:xs) = n+x : f1 (n+x) xs
```

проверка:

```
> f [1,2,3,4]
[1,3,6,10]
```

Comment: Можно проще: `f = scanl1 (+)`

Comment: @AlexanderRazorenov , да, так короче, и даже, вероятно, быстрее, но зато менее наглядно.

Answer (score 1):

Так как условие `a[i]=a[i]+a[i-1] для i>0`, то нумерация элементов списка очевидно с нуля. Тогда решение задачи можно записать следующим образом

```
-- сложение элементов с предыдущим
addPrev [] = []
addPrev (x:xs) = x:(addPrev1 x xs) where
    addPrev1 _ [] = []
    addPrev1 z1 (z:zs) = (z1+z):(addPrev1 z zs)

-- фильтрация нечётных (нумерация с нуля, судя по постановке задачи)
filterOdds _ _ [] = []
filterOdds _ _ (x:[]) = [x]
filterOdds s l (x:y:xs)
    | y*l < s = x:(filterOdds s l xs)
    | otherwise = x:y:(filterOdds s l xs)

-- собираем всё в один алгоритм
processList xs = filterOdds (sum newList) (length newList) newList where
    newList = addPrev xs
```

Для проверки можно выполнить `processList [1,2,3,4]`.

Поясню, почему такая странная на первый взгляд проверка на среднее: не сравнение с числом, а умножение элемента на длину списка и сравнение с суммой. Это сделано, чтобы не связываться с делением, которое в Haskell определено не для всех числовых типов.

Comment: И да, индекс по списку Вы нашли - операция `(!!)`, но для решения данной задачи она не нужна. И ещё извлекать элементы списка по индексу в общем случае не эффективно, так как список Haskell ближе к итераторам, чем к массивам. Для массивов в Haskell есть другие типы.

Comment: В вашем решении программа работает не совсем так как нужно, а точнее  функция `addPrev`. Например, для массива `addPrev [8,-2,4]` результат будет `[8,6,2]`, а должно получится `[8,6,10]` т.е. нужно складывать не `8+(-2)=6 -2+4=2`  а `8+(-2)=6 6+4=10`. Буду весьма благодарен, если Вы поправите свой код, чтобы он именно менял изначальный массив.

Comment: это не очевидно, из текста вопроса :) В таком случае функция `addPrev` не нужна совсем, а строку `newList = addPrev xs` нужно заменить на `newList = scanl1 (+) xs`